# No se insertan a la BD los valores de la etiqueta select con auto llenado utilizando [foreach] laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Estoy creando el formulario para la tabla contrato, la cual contiene cuatro campos foráneos, los cuales estoy trabajando con la etiqueta `select` y con `foreach` para mostrar los valores de las tablas con la que esta relacionada la tabla contrato.  [image: base de datos]

El problema es que cuando creó el contrato, solo se inserta en la base de datos los valores que corresponden a los campos jornada, PeriodoDePrueba, Salario y FechaInicio. Originando el siguiente error:

> Trying to get property 'Tipo' of non-object.  Sobre la vista
>   listacontratos.index que muestra los contratos creados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si inserto manualmente en el HeidiSQL de laragon los valores faltantes, el error se soluciona y redirige al index correctamente mostrando el contrato recién creado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código del controlador:

```
public function create()
{
    $tipodecontrato = Tipo_de_contrato::pluck('Tipo','id_tipoDeContrato');
    $cargo = Cargo::pluck('Cargo','id_cargo');

    $empleado = Empleado::pluck('Nombre','id_empleado');
    $empresa = Empresa::pluck('Empresa','id_empresa');

    return view('listacontratos.create', compact('tipodecontrato','cargo', 'empleado','empresa'));
}  

public function store(CreateContratoRequest $request)
{
    //return $request->all();
    $listacontratos = \App\Contrato::create( $request->all() );

    return redirect()->route('contratos.index');

}
```

Este es el formulario de crear contrato:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row contacto">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h5 class="tituloContacto">Crear Contrato </h5>

            @if (session()->has('info'))
                <div class="alert alert-success">{{ session('info') }}</div>
            @endif

            <div class="card-group">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card bg-light mb-3 text-center">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('contratos.store') }}"><!--empleados.update esta ruta se verifica en la consola con php artisan r:l en caso de no ser encontrada-->
                            {!!csrf_field() !!} 
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 pt-3">
                                    <label for="nombre">Jornada</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Jornada" value="{{ $listacontratos->Jornada or old('Jornada') }}">
                                    <small id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
                                    {!!$errors->first('Jornada','<span class=error>:message</span>')!!}
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 pt-3">
                                    <label for="nombre">PeriodoDePrueba</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="PeriodoDePrueba" value="{{ $listacontratos->PeriodoDePrueba or old('PeriodoDePrueba') }}">
                                    <small id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
                                    {!!$errors->first('PeriodoDePrueba','<span class=error>:message</span>')!!}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 pt-3">
                                    <label for="nombre">Salario</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="Salario" name="Salario" value="{{ $listacontratos->Salario or old('Salario') }}">
                                    <small id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
                                    {!!$errors->first('Salario','<span class=error>:message</span>')!!}
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 pt-3">
                                    <label for="nombre">Fecha de inicio</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="FechaInicio" value="{{ $listacontratos->FechaInicio or old('FechaInicio') }}" required>
                                    {!!$errors->first('fechacontrato','<span class=error>:message</span>')!!}
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 pt-5">
                                    <label for="nombre">Tipo de contrato</label>
                                    <select class="form-control custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect" type="input" name="tipodecontrato" required>
                                        <option value="" selected>seleccionar</option>  
                                        @foreach ($tipodecontrato as $id_tipoDeContrato =>$Tipo)    
                                            <option value="{{$id_tipoDeContrato}}"> {{$Tipo }} </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    {!!$errors->first('tipodecontrato','<span class=error>:message</span>')!!}
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 pt-5">
                                    <label for="nombre">Cargo</label>
                                    <select class="form-control custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect" type="input" name="cargo" required>
                                        <option value=""  selected>seleccionar</option> 
                                        @foreach ($cargo as $id_cargo =>$Cargo)    
                                            <option value="{{$id_cargo}}"> {{$Cargo }} </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    {!!$errors->first('cargo','<span class=error>:message</span>')!!}
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 pt-5">
                                    <label for="nombre">Empleado</label>
                                    <select class="form-control custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect" type="input" name="empleado" required>
                                        <option value=""  selected>seleccionar</option> 
                                        @foreach ($empleado as $id_empleado =>$Nombre)    
                                            <option value="{{$id_empleado}}"> {{$Nombre }} </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    {!!$errors->first('empleado','<span class=error>:message</span>')!!}
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 pt-5">
                                    <label for="nombre">Empresa</label>
                                    <select class="form-control custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect" type="input" name="empresa" required>
                                        <option value=""  selected>seleccionar</option> 
                                        @foreach ($empresa as $id_empresa =>$Empresa)    
                                            <option value="{{$id_empresa}}"> {{$Empresa }} </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    {!!$errors->first('empresa','<span class=error>:message</span>')!!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                                    <input class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Guardar">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                                    <a href="{{ url('lista/contratos') }}" class="btn btn-link-primary btn-sm">Regresar</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y estos son los valores que salen del formulario al retornar todo el request:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe resaltar que si yo cambio la etiqueta `select` por un `input`, los valores se insertan correctamente, pero el `input` para estos campos foráneos no me sirven. También hice pruebas con la etiqueta de html5 datalist y obtengo el mismo problema, pareciera que el problema esta en el `foreach`, pero no se como solucionarlo.

Estas son las relaciones en el modelo Contrato:

```
class Contrato extends Model
   {
      protected $table = 'contrato';
      protected $primaryKey = 'id_contrato';
      protected $fillable = ['Jornada','PeriodoDePrueva','Salario','FechaInicio','id_tipoDeContrato','id_cargo','id_empleado','id_empresa'];

      public function tipodecontrato()
      {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Tipo_de_contrato','id_tipoDeContrato');
      }

      public function cargo()
      {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Cargo','id_cargo');
      }

      public function empleado()
      {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Empleado','id_empleado');
      }

      public function empresa()
      {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Empresa','id_empresa');
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div class="col-12 col-md-6 pt-5">
  <label for="nombre">Tipo de contrato</label>
  <select class="form-control custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect" type="input" name="id_tipoDeContrato" required>
     <option value="" selected>seleccionar</option>  
      @foreach ($tipodecontrato as $id_tipoDeContrato =>$Tipo)    
        <option value="{{$id_tipoDeContrato}}"> {{$Tipo }} </option>
      @endforeach
  </select>
  {!!$errors->first('tipodecontrato','<span class=error>:message</span>')!!}
 </div>
```

> El problema era que en la variable `name` de la etiqueta `select` no estaba colocando el nombre del campo de la tabla contrato, en este caso `id_tipoDeContrato`.

```
name="id_tipoDeContrato"
```

La variable `name`  se encarga de pasar los valores al `request` en el controlador metodo `store`

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el helper `optional()` de Laravel, el cual te entrega null cuando una propiedad (en este caso) no está definida, en vez de arrojar un error:

```
{{ optional($listacontrato->tipodecontrato)->Tipo }}
```

Puedes revisar su documentación aquí: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-optional

---

Un apunte adicional respecto a tu convención de nombres: En Laravel se sigue de forma oficial el estándar PSR-2 y normalmente utilizamos camelCase para los nombres de variables, propiedades, etc.

Te sugeriría que cambies los nombres a algo así:

```
{{ optional($listaContrato->tipoDeContrato)->tipo }}
```

Esto las hará mucho más legibles y además permitirá una conversión directa a otras convenciones como snake_case, utilizada comunmente en las bases de datos.

P.D. Creo que prueBa es con B, a menos que lo hayas utilizado intencionalmente con V para evitar algún conflicto.

Comment: De momento el  error se arregló, pero sigo sin poder insertar a la base de datos los campos que corresponden a las llaves foráneas de las otras tablas relacionadas con la tabla contrato, Los input me funcionan, pero las cuatro etiquetas select que estoy usando en el formulario de contrato, no se insertan a la base de datos los valores posibles que ya tengo definidos utilizando el foreach

Comment: idea que yo tenía era que si lograba insertar a la BD los valores faltantes, el error desaparecería sin necesidad de optional() function. No sé por qué se inserta null, si al retornar todo el request en el controlador (public function store), se muestra aparentemente normal los valores seleccionados en el formulario.

Comment: Voy a revisar, tal vez no entendí algo.